# How can I get a multiple of 3 using a for-loop and a function in my code in c?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

I want to solve the problem of taking an integer and finding a multiple of 3.
My code is as follows.

```
#includ <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    xum(a);
}

void xum(int a)
{
    int xum,a,bum=0;
    for (a=1;bum<=a,++bum){
        if (bum%3==0){
            printf("%d",bum);
        }
    }
}
```

This code uses C.
Inside the function I get an error like this:
error: 'a' redeclared as different kind of symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Well you get `a` as input, then you send it as parameter to your function and then you redeclare it as one of `xum` variables.

If you want to find a multiple between 0 and 3 you should change your loop to run from 0 to `a` the argument of xum, and as I said before, change the variable a name